# Dragonfly mailer configuration with STARTTLS

Tags: smtp, freebsd, openssl

We are trying to get a *dragonfly* mta (dma) client to use STARTTLS with our mailhub.  We created a self-signed certificate and key using `openssl`

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -x509 -sha256 -set_serial 201912200501 -days 3650 -nodes -out x.crt -keyout x.key
```

and concatenated these into a pem file:

```
cat x.crt x.key > /usr/local/etc/pki/tls/private/x.pem ; chmod 600 /usr/local/etc/pki/tls/private/x.pem
```

In /etc/dma.conf we have this:

```
SECURETRANSFER
STARTTLS
CERTFILE = /usr/local/etc/pki/tls/private/x.pem
```

When we try to send to the mail hub dma reports this in `/var/log/maillog`:

```
Dec 20 16:15:54 gway05 dma[2813d.8018280f0]: trying remote delivery to smtp.hamilton.harte-lyne.ca [216.185.71.31] pref 0
Dec 20 16:15:54 gway05 dma[2813d.8018280f0]: SSL: Cannot load certificate `= /usr/local/etc/pki/tls/private/x.pem': error:140DC002:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:system lib
Dec 20 16:15:54 gway05 dma[2813d.8018280f0]: remote delivery deferred
```

What are we doing wrong?

Comment: Looking at the error message, it seems to be using the `= ` as part of the pathname. Try: `CERTFILE /usr/local/etc/pki/tls/private/x.pem`

Comment: Thanks.  I made the change to dma.conf to remove the = but the problem remains: `Dec 23 09:17:49 gway05 dma[28a88.8018280f0]: SSL: Cannot load certificate '/usr/local/etc/pki/tls/private/gway05_ss.pem': error:140DC002:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:system lib`.  The = is gone from the error message but hat is about the only change.

Comment: The certificate that we are using is a self-signed openssl rsa generated using: `openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -x509 -sha256 -set_serial 201912200501 -days 3650 -nodes -out gway05_ss.crt -keyout gway05_ss.key`   Openssl verify shows exactly what we expect:
`openssl verify /usr/local/etc/pki/tls/private/gway05_ss.pem`  `/usr/local/etc/pki/tls/private/gway05_ss.pem: C = CA, ST = Ontario, L = Hamilton, O = Harte & Lyne Limited, OU = IT, CN = gway05.hamilton.harte-lyne.ca, emailAddress = support@harte-lyne.ca
error 18 at 0 depth lookup:self signed certificate
OK`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `error:140DC002:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:system lib` is caused by the `pem` file not being readable by the `wheel` group. changing the permissions on `/usr/local/etc/pki/tls/private/gway05_ss.pem` to `-rw-r-----  1 root  wheel` resolves the issue.